# Using a mid 2010 27" iMac as a second screen for a mid 2015 27" 5k iMac

Tags: display, imac, thunderbolt, displayport, target-display

I would like to use my ageing 27" iMac (mid 2010 model) as a second screen for my mid 2015 5k model as my even older 24" Cinema Display finally gave up the ghost. I have tried hooking them up using a lightning cable and putting it in target display mode using the standard Command+F2 and also Command+Fn+F2 but nothing happens. Do I need a thunderbolt > mini displayport cable/adapter or mdp > mdp? It would be great if anyone can share any experience of this before I buy one. Thanks.

Comment: How did you manage to connect the two iMacs together using a lightning cable?

Comment: It turns out that's not possible. I bought a Thunderbolt > Mini DisplayPort cable and it works perfectly!